# How to pull an exhaustive list of securities traded globally, on bloomberg?

Tags: data

I need to extract an exhaustive list of securities with CUSIPs and ISINs on bloomberg. This data needs to be on a global level. Can someone help with the formulae on bloomberg please?

Cheers,
G

Answer (score 2):

Just use the EQS function and grab all active securities (primary listing only unless you want the same one per each exchange)

Specify in the resultscreen for isin and cusips in the add columns field

Click results in EQS
Enter ISIN in the Add column entry and hit enter (repeat that for cusip too)

Comment: Thank you!! Can you please specify the steps to get the end result for ISIN and CUSIPs? Also, is there any online source as an alternative to bloomberg?

Comment: also, can you please share how to extract all listings (other than primary listings), country traded in, industry and sector etc..

Comment: Just enter those into the fields in the results screen of EQS, I updated the answer with the instructions

Comment: Hi Kyle, thank you for your prompt help and reply. Will this help me retrieve securities in all listings ie. primary and otherwise?

Comment: also, will this also help to extract securities traded on OTC?

Comment: You can specify that in the search I assume the default is yes but in can be precised in EQS

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try http://bsym.bloomberg.com/sym/ see left bottom part "predefined files".

Comment: Also maybe some samples here can help too : ftp://ftp.nyxdata.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should press the green "help" key on the Bloomberg terminal twice to communicate with their helpdesk.

However, in general you can simply use the "BDP(CUSIP, PRICE)" or "BDH(CUSIP, PRICE; STARTDATE, ENDDATE)" function with Bloomberg's Excel Addin (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080470/bloomberg-bhd-function-with-isin).

Comment: Thank you!! Can you please specify the steps to get the end result for ISIN and CUSIPs? Also, is there any online source as an alternative to bloomberg?